# C++ Concepts : CRTP

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

It's probably just that the concept is bad, but I can't see why. And didn't find any example with constructor. Or maybe it has nothing to do with the constructor...

```
template < typename T >
concept bool C_Object() {
  return requires {

    T();
  };
}

template < C_Object Object>
class  DefaultManager {

  //  Content;
};

template < C_Object Derived >
class  Component {

  // Content
};

struct Test : public Component<Test> {

  int data;

  Test() = default;
};

int main() {

  Test test;
  return 0;
}
```

Give the error :

```
test2.cpp:21:36: error: template constraint failure
 struct Test : public Component<Test> {
                                    ^
test2.cpp:21:36: note:   constraints not satisfied
test2.cpp:2:14: note: within ‘template<class T> concept bool C_Object() [with T = Test]’
 concept bool C_Object() {
              ^~~~~~~~
test2.cpp:2:14: note: the required expression ‘T()’ would be ill-formed
```

That sound like a : "Hey my code is broken, please fix it", sorry.

Anyway thanks

Have a great day

Comment: You know that concepts didn't make it to the standard?

Comment: @SergeyA yes probably c++20

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
struct Test : public Component<Test> {
```

Whenever you so much as *name* a specialization of a constrained class template, the given parameters are validated against the constraints. In this particular case, that means that `C_Object<Test>` is checked for satisfaction, but since `Test` is incomplete - the compiler hasn't parsed its definition yet - `C_Object` is not satisfied.

This is the "concepts" version of the classical problem with CRTP bases: you must delay inspection of the derived class until its definition is complete.

Comment: I even didn't know about CRTP. Too much for this night I think.
If you're crazy enough I love an explanation :)
But anyway I'm really lucky that you was there.
PS : I'll close the question when I'll read about CRTP and stuffs (Tomorrow).

Comment: Even on StackOverflow : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19886041/will-concepts-lite-change-the-need-of-crtp-to-achieve-static-polymorphism?rq=1
I didn't find why my code is not working, the CRTP seems to be okay (works perfect without concepts). I must delay inspection of the derived class as you said, but can't find any information about that.

Comment: @MathieuVanNevel the usual way I achieve the delaying you mention is by making sure to [make the types re-dependent](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ebce3da07046ba3), informally speaking (i.e. I'm really using an actually dependent type).

Comment: That seems to be tricky with the constructor, but I'll try something. Thanks for the code, I was thinking it was not necessary. There is a lot of meta programming tricky like this?

Comment: @MathieuVanNevel as a heads-up that particular technique cannot work for things that can't be templates, such as the copy/move constructors and assignment operators as well as the destructor. it works for constructor templates though.

Answer (score 5):

I found the most readable option to be an "impl" method with a constrained return type. Let's take the example in [Luc Danton's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40853060/c-concepts-crtp#comment68959314_40853437) and transfer it to C++20:

```
template <typename Var>
concept Fooable = requires(Var var) {
  {var.foo()};
};

template <typename Derived>
struct mixin {
  void bar() { impl().foo(); }
  Fooable auto& impl() { return static_cast<Derived&>(*this); } // Constrain return here!
};

// no constraint violation
struct ex1 : mixin<ex1> {
  void foo() {}
};

// no violation either
struct ex2 : mixin<ex2> {};

int main() {
  // mixin<ex1>::bar constraints respected
  ex1{}.bar();

  // mixin<ex2>::bar constraints violation
  ex2{}.bar();
}
```