# Issues with C++ Concepts and Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP)

Tags: c++, templates, c++-concepts, crtp

I am trying to create a serialization interface for some message classes. I also am trying to create some concepts that check the types of these messages to verify they have static `Serialize` functions.

I have a concept to test if a type `T` has a static function called `Serialize` that takes in an instance of a `T` object and returns a vector of chars.

```
template <typename T>
concept HasSerialize = requires(T obj)
{
    { T::Serialize(obj) } -> std::same_as<std::vector<unsigned char>>;
};
```

This is my base class that uses the concept as a template argument.

```
template <HasSerialize MessageType>
class MessageBase
{
public:
    static std::vector<unsigned char> Serialize(MessageType message)
    {
        return MessageType::Serialize(message);
    }
};
```

And this is my derived class that uses the CRTP.

```
class PutMessage : public MessageBase<PutMessage>
{
public:
    static std::vector<unsigned char> Serialize(PutMessage message)
    {
        std::vector<unsigned char> v = {'a', 'b', 'c'}; // Test data
        return v;
    }
};
```

Whenever I compile, the compiler gives me the following error

```
error: constraints not satisfied for class template 'MessageBase' [with MessageType = PutMessage]

because 'PutMessage' does not satisfy 'HasSerialize'
    template <HasSerialize MessageType>

because 'T::Serialize(obj)' would be invalid: no member named 'Serialize' in 'PutMessage'
        { T::Serialize(obj) } -> std::same_as<std::vector<unsigned char>>;
```

I think I might be misunderstanding these concepts or I am not accounting for some reference type or cv-qualified type. I am a bit stumped on how to fix this or if it is even fixable. To me it looks like the constraint is satisfied. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40853060/c-concepts-crtp

Comment: you could only put the constraint on `MessageBase::Serialize`, though it will trigger an error only later https://godbolt.org/z/sYo4axh1x

Comment: btw when the method is static you dont need crtp. You merely need a `Serializer<MessageType>` that calls `MessageType::Serialize`. This will also make your current issue go away. Though, I suppose you are only showing a simplified example

Comment: on the other hand, if you clarify the question to state whether this is the only (static) member of `PutMessage` and crtp is not essential for your solution, I guess the question could be reopened to provide an answer without crtp

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number
This is not the only static member of `PutMessage` I have a few static members that eventually need to be checked in a compound requires statement.

Comment: if they are all static, then you do not need crtp, or do you need it?

Comment: Also the answers to the other question do not go into detail about how to delay inspection. I think I understand that having the line `class PutMessage : public MessageBase<PutMessage>` already forces inspection on the `PutMessage` class even before it's complete. But how do we delay this then?

Comment: yes they do https://stackoverflow.com/a/65085674/4117728

Comment: I think i still need CRTP as I will eventually have other message types that will be static cast inside the base class. Each of the derived classes will have their own serialize implementation so I'm not seeing why I would not need CRTP.

Comment: i dont see how you want to have some derived classes that you need to cast and some that you dont. Though, anyhow, if you are fixed on CRTP then the dupe is the answer

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. Eventually I expect all the classes to be cast in the base class.

Comment: no there is no misunderstanding, I wanted to know if you do need CRTP. You say you do. The code you posted looks like you do not, because this is constrained and achieves the same without crtp it does not have the issue you are now facing with crtp https://godbolt.org/z/z5v576boh

Comment: Yes, that was a miscommunication on my part. The code here does not reflect my end goal. It was meant to illustrate one of my hurdles.

Comment: no worries. The question is perfectly clear. I only wanted to make sure that it is not a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Its sometimes hard to know if the asker confuses a hammer with a screwdriver or its just by simplification of the code that the screw looks like a nail. For the nail there would have been simple solution not covered in the duplicate, but for your screw the duplicate is just fine I think

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll try to look at that 2nd answer on the other post a bit more to see if I understand. From a first pass read, it looks like pulling the concept out of the template argument and instead placing it on a return type allows this to work.

I still have to understand why this delays inspection.

Comment: its similar to what I proposed in first comment above https://godbolt.org/z/sYo4axh1x

Comment: Wonderful! That absolutely worked!

Do you mind elaborating on why pushing down the template constraint to the function delays inspection? Maybe I didn't say that correctly.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number
Oh I think I see it. It's because the inner template on the function is not specialized until we call `Serialize` with an instantiated base class so it does not need to check the hasSerializable constraint during the class construction phase.

Comment: exactly. Its similar to this https://godbolt.org/z/vsbE7Gz1b