# CRTP and recursively defining a concept

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

There are questions already regarding this (eg. [C++ Concepts : CRTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40853060/c-concepts-crtp)) but afaict the answers do not really say how to solve the underlying issue.

I want to define recursively a concept. Something along the following lines. A type models `concept_0` if it is integral. And a type models `concept_{n+1}` if it is a range of `concept_n` elements. I would like something like the following to compile

```cpp
template <typename R>
concept my_object = std::integral<R> || (std::ranges::sized_range<R> && my_object<typename R::value_type>);
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: They don't mention how to solve it because this is not "solvable" in the way most folks want it "solved". Concepts are not designed to do that, and so won't let you try.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, concepts do not allow recursion. But templates do, so to get your example to work, you could write a template class that models your concept and then just define your concept as a thin wrapper around that:

```cpp
template <typename R>
struct my_object : std::false_type
{};

// specialization for integral types
template <std::integral R>
struct my_object<R>
 : public std::true_type
{};

// specialization for ranges using recursion
template <std::ranges::sized_range R>
struct my_object<R>
 : public std::conditional_t<
    my_object<typename R::value_type>::value,
    std::true_type, 
    std::false_type
>
{};

// wrapping in a concept
template <typename R>
concept my_object_concept = my_object<R>::value;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/1fqKzrYGh

Comment: Thanks this is useful! you can use `template <std::integral R>` and `template <std::ranges::sized_range R>` to make it slightly more readable

Comment: True. Edited the answer accordingly

Comment: Note this technique does not support "subsumes".  So, for example, a "range of this concept" isn't subsumed by "an integral, or a range of this concept".

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont, I think you are right. I can't think of any way to support subsumption.

Comment: @joergbrech A very stupid finite recusive depth could be supported by horrible code.  But it would be horrible and fragile.

Answer (score 3):

Do it the old-fashioned way:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

template <typename R> 
  struct is_my_object
  {
    static constexpr bool value = false;
  };

template <std::integral R>
  struct is_my_object<R>
  {
    static constexpr bool value = true;
  };

template <std::ranges::sized_range R>
  struct is_my_object<R>
  {
    static constexpr bool value = is_my_object<typename R::value_type>::value;
  };

template <typename R>
concept my_object = is_my_object<R>::value;

static_assert(my_object<int>);
static_assert(!my_object<float>);
static_assert(my_object<std::vector<int>>);
static_assert(my_object<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>);
```

(This definition will fail on `my_object<int[2]>`; fixing this problem is an easy exercise).

Comment: Not sure if you wrote it this way just to highlight the purpose, but `template <std::ranges::sized_range R> struct is_my_object<R> : is_my_object<typename R::value_type> {};` is a lot more concise for the last partial specialization.

Comment: Thank you, both these answers are useful!

Comment: @ReimundoHeluani they are practically the same, modulo minor details ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your type trait doesn't actually need three template definitions in order to implement this concept, since there's only two cases to handle. Also, using [`std::ranges::range_value_t<R>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iterator_t) instead of `typename R::value_type` allows you to check C-style array types as well.

```cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <ranges>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template <class R>
struct is_my_object : std::is_integral<R> {};

template <std::ranges::sized_range R>
struct is_my_object<R> : is_my_object<std::ranges::range_value_t<R>> {};

template <class R>
concept my_object = is_my_object<R>::value;

static_assert(my_object<int>);
static_assert(not my_object<float>);
static_assert(my_object<std::vector<int>>);
static_assert(my_object<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>);
static_assert(my_object<int[2]>);
static_assert(not my_object<int[]>);
```

https://godbolt.org/z/5Krb6cosv